# How do you set include_granted_scopes=true using Google's Java OAuth client?

Tags: google-oauth-java-client

I am successfully using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow to obtain and store credentials to access the Google Calendar API. I would like to use the `include_granted_scopes=true` query parameter for [incremental authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#incrementalAuth).

I searched for a long time but could not figure out how to include the `include_granted_scopes` parameter. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

First get your authorization url

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl authUrl = googleAuthorizationCodeFlow.newAuthorizationUrl();
```

The authorization url is just an instance of a `GenericUrl`, so you can use [GenericUrl.set(key, value)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/GenericUrl#set(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) to set an arbitrary query parameter.

```
authUrl.set("include_granted_scopes", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var googleOAuthOptions = 
    new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        ClientId = "...",
        ClientSecret = "...",

        Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnApplyRedirect = context =>
                        {
                            var redirect = context.RedirectUri;
                            redirect += "&include_granted_scopes=true";
                            context.Response.Redirect(redirect);

                        }
                    }
    };

googleOAuthOptions.Scope.Add(...);

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuthOptions);
```